# Is there a way to achieve smoother transitions between images using lightbox2?

Tags: javascript, image-gallery, transition, lightbox2

I'm using Lightbox2: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/.

The plugin seems to have been written in a way that produces a 'flash' effect when navigating to a new image in a collection. I believe this is because the old image simply disappears, rather than fading out first or crossfading (this would be ideal) with the new image that is fading in.

For a demo of this flaw, just view the example on the Lightbox2 link above.

Is there a way to add some sort of fade out transition when the user advances to the next image? As a developer rather unskilled in JS, what could I add to the lightbox.js script that would allow me to achieve 100% smooth transitions between images?

Comment: Just realized that this has come up before on the plugin's repo: https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/415 and https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/321. I'm not sure where the developer would prefer these discussions to take place. I'm assuming maybe on github because it's more of a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

I can't work out a way to fade out the image like you suggested, but I think this really helps to avoid the white flash between images.

In the lightbox.css file between lines 43 and 51, simply change the background colour to black, or something similar, basically meaning you'll get a black flash instead of white. If you still want a white border around the image, just add one here (You'll also need to remove lines 59 to 61). So you'll end up with this:

```
.lb-outerContainer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 4px solid white;
}
```

Also, if you're not happy with the fade in speed, take a look at line 313 in the lightbox.js file.
Specifically on line 316, change ('slow') to a numerical value e.g. (800).

```
// Display the image and its details and begin preload neighboring images.
 Lightbox.prototype.showImage = function() {
    this.$lightbox.find('.lb-loader').stop(true).hide();
    this.$lightbox.find('.lb-image').fadeIn('slow');

    this.updateNav();
    this.updateDetails();
    this.preloadNeighboringImages();
    this.enableKeyboardNav();
  };
```